# Uninstalling updates using wusa.exe

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I am trying to write a powershell script which uninstalls updates.

My problem is that the script doesn't run the `wusa.exe` when starting the script.

```
function Uninstall-Hotfix () {
    [string]$parameters = "KB4041691"
    [string]$KBs = @()

    if ($parameters.Contains(":")) {
        [object]$arguments = $parameters.Split(":")
        foreach ($argument in $arguments) {
            $argument.Replace("KB", "")
            $KBs.add($argument)

            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $KBs.length; $i++) {
                Cmd /c wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:$KBs[$i] /quiet /norestart
                Do {
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
                }
                while (Wait-Process | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "wusa"}) 

                If (Get-Hotfix -Id $KBs[$i] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                    Write-Host "KB $KBs[$i] Fehlerhaft"
                }
                Else {
                    Write-Host "KB $KBs[$i] Erfolgreich deinstalliert"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Else {
        $parameter = $parameters.Replace("KB", "")
        $parameter
        cmd /c wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:$parameter /quiet /norestart
        Do {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
        }
        while (Wait-Process | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "wusa.exe"})
    }
}
Uninstall-Hotfix
```

Comment: cmd isn't a command, read the error message. Use Start-process or call wusa.exe directly

Comment: Try `& wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:$parameter /quiet /norestart`

Comment: @guiwhatsthat: Powershell shows no error and i saw other scripts also using "cmd" command...

Comment: @JamesC.: This doesn't work either :( ... I saw in the event viewer that he logged a syntax error at application because he couldn't read the kb number... now he doesn't log a error but it still doesn't run or uninstall the update...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very heavy and in my opinion contains too much loops, you can try this :

```
function Uninstall-Hotfix () {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][array]$Patches
    )

    foreach($patch in $Patches){
        $numKb = $null
        if($patch -match "\d{7}"){
            [int]$numkb = $Matches[0]
            Write-Host $numKb

            Start-Process wusa.exe -ArgumentList "/KB:$numKb /uninstall /quiet /norestart" -Wait

            if(Get-Hotfix -Id $numKb -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
                Write-Host "KB $KBs[$i] Fehlerhaft"
            }
            else{
                Write-Host "KB $KBs[$i] Erfolgreich deinstalliert"
            }
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "KB is not valid"
        }
    }
}
Uninstall-Hotfix -Patches KB4041691,KB1234567
```

Comment: Thank you. But this still doesn't work. I found out that when I don't use the parameter "/quiet" he opens wusa and asks me if I want to uninstall it. When I use the "/quiet" parameter he does nothing and I can't see a wusa process... Any ideas why this isn't working? Thank you so far.

Comment: It seems it's not a Powershell issue. If you're on Windows 10, you can take a look at this post : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f6594e00-2400-4276-85a1-fb06485b53e6/issues-with-wusaexe-and-windows-10-enterprise?forum=win10itprogeneral

Comment: We use our Remote Monitoring & Management to roll out the script (all machines use windows 7) but we can't when I can't use the "/quiet" switch... I also found out that when you use the "/uninstall /kb:.." switch you can't use "/quiet". But when you use the "/uninstall <Update>" switch you can use "/quiet". But what does this <Update> mean? When you open wusa.exe without parameters it show you the available parameters...

Comment: _But what does this <Update> mean?_ : wusa /uninstall /kb:{update ID}. You get the correct command. See the link above, it could help you. Another link : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/does-windows-provide-a-way-to-uninstall-security/b616c77d-609c-4ca1-b6f9-5f14b661166e?auth=1